# Data exchange between academic institutions

Tags: data

Is there any publicly available statistics on the amount of exchange of data that transit through Internet between academic institutions? (e.g. X TB yearly from institution A to institution B)

Comment: Including or excluding cat movies? (SCNR. I wonder how such a study could even be set up, with everyone using DropBox and similar services for large data sets. I'd therefore not trust such statistics overmuch.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa including cat movies. Yes, I don't expect data transiting via 3rd party applications to be easily countable: just focusing on direct connections (i.e. what network admins could see).

Comment: You should look at statistics from the different research networks that exist. For instance, the european GEANT network claims to transfer over 1000 Terabytes per day (!) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%89ANT . The US has the Internet2 backbone which is mainly for academic institutions and I expect they are moving even more than 1000 Terabytes per day.

Answer (score 1):

In France, the network [RENATER](https://www.renater.fr/statistiques-reseau?lang=fr), which connect many universities, publish some [statistics](https://www.renater.fr/statistiques-reseau?lang=fr) showing the live load of links:

(the French phrase "charge des liens" in the legend means link load)

Paris area:

[image]

Metropolitan France:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brazil has similar resources for the RNP: http://www.rnp.br/servicos/conectividade/trafego

Comment: This seems to be like Internet2 in the US. But I suspect that most data transfer happens over the public Internet, not over these research/educational networks.

Comment: (Also, since these research/educational networks are widely used for experimenting with networks, they tend to carry a lot of "fake" data, which may or may not be useful to you in the context of this question.)